# (K)Ubuntu with NVidia GeForce RTX 3060 TI freezes during boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, drivers, nvidia

after having spent four days of trying virtually every single idea and suggestion that I came across, I now admit to being utterly and totally dumbfounded by the problem that I'm facing. I would appreciate, if somebody could point me in the right direction. My problem is as follows:

I'm currently setting up a new computer with the following specs:

- Mainboard: *Mag B560 Tomahawk WIFI by MSI*
- Graphics card: **GeForce RTX 3060 Ti** *by KFA2*
- CPU: *Intel i7-11700KF*
- Three screens, two of which are connected via DisplayPort, one via HDMI.
- Secure Boot is disabled.
- Fast Boot is disabled.

I installed the latest version of **KUbuntu Linux** (Jammy Jellyfish 22.04, as of this writing) and initially managed to get the system running more or less directly out-of-the-box. However, after having installed a few necessary updates and lots of programs, the problems started:

In a nutshell, it has now turned out to be virtually impossible to get the system to **boot**, as it always **freezes** before switching to the graphical login screen. From the beginning I suspected the NVidia drivers to be at least part of the problem and started to boot by removing `quiet splash` from the GRUB entry and added `noplymouth nomodeset` to better understand what's happening. I then noticed that the boot process mostly froze, when the USB ports where queried and managed to locate a problem with one of my tablets. By moving this from a USB 2 to a USB 3 port, the problem went away, i.e. the boot process no longer stops there and runs roughly until the graphical login screen should appear.

I then read about a bug related to having screens connected to a DisplayPorts in some versions of the NVidia driver (e.g. [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/465-24-02-page-fault/175782/178) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/nuwko0/ubuntu_2004_wont_boot_when_switching_to_nvidia)). However, the versions mentioned in these threads don't seem to be relevant for my card anymore. What's more, I also tried booting with only a monitor plugged into a HDMI port, without any luck.

I then proceeded to trying different versions of the driver with varying results:

- *450-server* (from the repositories, mentioned in one of the threads above): resulted in lots of errors "Failed to start nvidia persistence daemon".
- *460.84* (from the NVidia site): fails to compile
- *470.57* (from the NVidia site): fails to compile
- *470.63* (from the NVidia site): freezes before switching to the graphical login screen
- *470.63* (from the NVidia site): freezes before switching to the graphical login screen
- *470.94* (from the NVidia site): freezes before switching to the graphical login screen
- *470.103* (from the repositories): freezes before switching to the graphical login screen
- *510.60* (both from the repositories and from the NVidia site): freezes before switching to the graphical login screen.

In most cases, I managed to at least reach a console by booting to run level 3 (adding `3` in GRUB), where I could then uninstall the driver. However, in some cases, I had to explicitly blacklist the NVidia drivers (adding `module_blacklist=nvidia` in GRUB): In general, drivers with versions 510.xx seem to cause this more often, but I can't quite put my finger on the problems.

I then tried to boot an older kernel and switched from 5.15.0-27 to 5.15.0-25 (no other kernel is available). At first, this seemed to improve things, as I managed to get the system to boot using drivers versions 470.63 and onwards. Alas, my joy was shortlived, as the problems came back. I now seem to be able to boot to a working system once every, say, 50 times. In these cases, however, only one of my screens is detected.

That made me suspect it might have something to do with timing. I came across a [thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1895521#p1895521) that suggested to *"load the Nvidia kernel modules a little earlier in the boot process"* by modifying `/etc/modules`. But this didn't seem to have any effect in my case.

The fact that only one of my three screens was detected, whenever I'm able to boot, made me suspect, the driver didn't even get loaded. And indeed: I now noticed *"(EE) Failed to load module nvidia (module does not exist, 0)"* in `/var/logs/Xorg.0.log`, so I searched for the driver and found it was installed to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg`. At that point I had installed, purged and reinstalled different versions of the drivers often times, so I wondered, why none of these steps had set the correct ModulePath. Nonetheless, I manually added the line `ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and managed to at least get the driver to load during boot. Unfortunately, I now get the error *"(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module"*. Checking `dmesg` doesn't contain any helpful hints.

Lastly, in my desperation I tried a simple `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` (that installed driver version 510.60). The system first booted into the latest kernel (-27, see above), which did not work, but switching back to the previous kernel version (-25) the system immediately booted with everything working perfectly. However, after only a single reboot, the problems came back and now even the autoinstall doesn't have any effect.

By the way:

- I made sure the `nouveau` driver is blacklisted.
- I tried to recreate the file `xorg.conf` using `sudo nvidia-xconfig` often and finally even deleted the whole directory `/etc/X11`. None of this has any effect.

---

I've now run out of ideas and I'd be happy about all hints and suggestions to get my system up and running.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds more like a hardware issue than software. Have you tried it with another GPU? Either another 3060 Ti or an older nvidia card? Or try re-seating the 3060 Ti in its PCI-e slot. Also try reseating your DIMMs. And try disabling any over-clocking or XMP memory profiles. BTW, I've had no stability problems with multiple versions of the kernel and multiple versions of the nvidia driver (debian dkms package, not upstream) with my 1060 6GB card (and previous nvidia cards including 560, 560 Ti, 960, 970) on multiple CPUs/motherboards from Phenom II to FX to Threadripper over many years.

Comment: nvidia's driver may be less than ideal compared to intel or radeon GPUs because it's a binary-only blob but in my experience, it has been remarkably stable and very high quality.  I expect I'll be switching to radeon for my next GPU upgrade, but (aside from the offense to my free software sensibilities), I don't regret using nvidia's proprietary driver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Actually, no, I haven't tried any other GPU, as I only have two rather old models available for testing (980 and 1070) and I suspect the fact that the *RTX 3060 Ti* is more recent to be part of the problem.
Personally, I have had good experiences running NVidia drivers in the past, as well, and didn't expect these problems at all. And I had the system up and running perfectly a few times - especially right at the beginning, after the first install. The troubles started after the updates, which makes me think there has to be something wrong.

Comment: You'll get more help here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggestion. :)